# git push shows no progression

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Background:

- cloned a large repo
- tried to push to own repo (failed due to size constraints)
- changed it's url to a gitlab url (from github)
- git cached some of the files and the progress immediately jumps to 31% of files pushed
- git is unresponsive to input (new lines are added upon new line but no progress update (stuck at 31% (above))
- using http auth

Is there a way to get git to show the actual status of the push?

Comment: The progress counter is counting by files, not by bytes sent. If the repo has one 10-gigabyte file, and 10-billion one-byte files, the counter will spin up reasonably fast until it hits the big file, appear to get stuck for however long it takes to send the one big file, then spin up fast again. (Technically it's counting by *objects*, but this is close enough for understanding.)